# Can magnetic susceptibility χ be -1?

Tags: magnetic-moment

Is it practically possible that the magnetic susceptibility of a substance is -1?

I thought so as such a substance could completely cancel the magnetic field, but I couldn't find anything as such.

Comment: A superconductor does this: the Meissner effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Superdiamagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdiamagnetism) ($\chi$ = -1) is a state that occurs in superconductors.

Normal [diamagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism#Theory) arises when electron spins in a material are induced to oppose the direction of an applied field; but the electrons are confined within their atomic orbitals, so the response is limited.

*Super*diamagnetism arises from the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect): the formation of screening currents which flow to oppose the applied field, these currents being persistent due to superconductivity. The currents flow without resistance, and grow to create a magnetic field which exactly opposes the applied field, resulting in zero net magnetic field within the superconductor.

The distance to which an applied field can penetrate below the surface of a superconductor is the [London penetration depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_penetration_depth). Inside the superconductor, $\chi$ is effectively -1.

Comment: I was under the impression that diamagnets also had persistent induced current, since there is no resistance inside the orbitals.